# "sudo service lightdm stop", no signal

Tags: 16.04, dell, gpu-driver

I accidentally enter `sudo service lightdm stop`. And then the desktop cannot connect to the display and says "No signal".
My desktop doesn't have a integrated graphics port. So I can only use the Nvidia gpu card port, but I have stopped it. 
How can I do?
My desktop is Precision 7820 Tower Workstation.

Comment: Have you tried starting the service again?  (via text terminal? or local or remote)

Comment: I haven't accidentally done that myself, nor have I accidentally learned about the command. But I guess I would accidentally try to use `sudo service lightdm start` to fix it. To help us learn more you could provide the link you "accidentally" found which led you to "accidentally" enter the command. Interesting fact, whilst taking of my backpack on a bus a few months ago my arm "accidentally" brushed against the next stop bell cord. I said to the driver "sorry I rang the next stop it was an accident". She said "there are no such things as accidents".

Comment: Thank guiverc and WinEunuuchs2Unix. I have restarted the service. There is no signal, so I cannot get into my desktop and open the terminal to enter "sudo service lightdm start"

Comment: Switch to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example), or `ssh` into the box  [*why I added the text terminal, local/remote bit to the end of my comment*] or if you're local, have you tried various ctrl+alt+fn combinations, certain things can trigger them to change.  You might need to go lower in the stack, restarting Xorg as a ~4year old release may have many things change/applied to it.